# Airflow delays in picking the dags from DAG folder

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

We are using airflow version 2 and when we place the DAG file in DAG folder, It takes 20 to 30 seconds to reflect the dag in the airflow dag list.

**NOTE** : we are using the Celery executor and postgres as database.

Could someone help me on how to make the airflow pick up the DAG faster?
Is there a configuration for it / any idea is appreciable.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to decrease `scheduler__min_file_process_interval` parameter (this will increase the CPU usage)

> Number of seconds after which a DAG file is parsed. The DAG file is
> parsed every min_file_process_interval number of seconds. Updates to
> DAGs are reflected after this interval. Keeping this number low will
> increase CPU usage.

However, it really depends on several factors - how many DAGs you have, how many file parsing processes, how many schedulers, sorting order, interval parameters.

See https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#id24 (scheduler parameters)

Also https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/scheduler.html#scheduler-tuneables has good overview of the tunables you can use

Generally your approach should be the same as for any performance improvement and optimisations. Airflow gives you a lot of "knobs" to turn but it's your task (depending on your particular deployment) to decide which knobs to turn.

For example If you see that you are saturating CPU, you might need to add another scheduler as your machine might be to slow to parse all your DAGs. But when you see that you have some CPUs free you might increase number of parsing processes. If you use remote filesystem and you see that you are blocked on i/o, you might want to increase capacity of the filesystem (usually cloud remote filesystem have limited throughput) etc. etc. You can also configure sorting order - i.e. which files are processed first.

I really recommend to watch the talk from Airflow Summit 2021 - https://youtu.be/DYC4-xElccE this might be useful to understand how scheduler work and what tuning you can do.

Comment: Thanks @Jarek, do we have any airflow api or cli command to forcefully read the dag from the dag folder ?

Comment: No. It's all controlled by scheduler processing.

Comment: I tuned the min file process interval and parsing processes but still It takes 30 to 40 seconds for airflow to pick up the dags ! Any other way to load the dags faster using scheduler ?

Comment: You need to see where your performance bottlenecks are. I am just working on a PR describing it - you might want to take a look https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/18356

Comment: Great help @JarekPotiuk. With CPU resource increments, its working fine.